# Запрос на получение данных с одной таблицы в обратном порядке с парметрами

Tags: php, mysql, sql, функции, phpmyadmin

Мне нужно чтобы выводились комментарии под каждую статью в обраном порядке, как правильно написать в SELECT, чтобы всё работало `$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY id DESC";` так это не работает

Вот весь код функции

```html
function selectAll($table, $params = []){
    global $pdo;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY id DESC";

    if(!empty($params)){
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($params as $key => $value){
            if (!is_numeric($value)){
                $value = "'".$value."'";
            }
            if ($i === 0){
                $sql = $sql . " WHERE $key=$value";
            }else{
                $sql = $sql . " AND $key=$value";
            }
            $i++;
        }
    }

    $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
    dbCheckError($query);
    return $query->fetchAll();
}
```

Comment: dbCheck ваш не говорит, что where не надо писать после order by ?

Comment: В SQL вашен порядок. SELECT -> FROM -> WHERE -> GROUP -> ORDER. Можно пропускать, нельзя менять местами.

Comment: У меня вроде как нечего не поменяно местами

Comment: Ну привет... а куда конкатенируется WHERE? не в середину же строки...

Comment: Сперва `$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE 1=1`, потом конкатенация условий (все - с `AND`, не надо устраивать эту дурь с `$i` ), и только после - конкатенация `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Вот так должно поулчится? $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE 1=1 AND ORDER BY id DESC";

Comment: @AdminConsole там либо не должно быть `AND` либо в `AND` должно быть условие еще одно условие.

Comment: у меня возникает такая ошибка (((  check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE page='' AND status=1' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

Собирать sql руками - очень-очень плохая идея. У вас тут полно sql-иньекций.

Возьмите параметизированные запросы. Псевдокод:

```
// SAFETY: переменной $table доверяем
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table";

if(!empty($params)){
    $sql = $sql . ' WHERE 1 = 1'
    foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
        // мы точно доверяем значению $key?
        $sql = $sql . " AND $key = ?";
    }
}
$sql = $sql . ' ORDER BY id DESC';

$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->execute([175, 'yellow']); // или bindParam
```

Comment: Спасибо!! подставил под свой код и всё заработало. $sql = $sql . ' ORDER BY id DESC'; Вот эту часть, после параметров